# Неверно выводит таблицы с данными

Tags: java, java-ee, транзакции

Столкнулся с проблемой, есть база данных с заказами пользователей. Есть метод, который согласно User id вытягивает заказы именно этого юзера. 
В юнитестах слой ДАО, Сервиса протестирован и все работает.

НО на стороне клиента при обновлении данные изменяются. Т.е, предположим юзер добавил 4 разных товара, потом 1 удалил. Обновляется страница и удаление не произошло, повторно обновляет бац и 3 товара, еще раз и опять 4.

На стороне сервера в базе все отображается корректно. Но на ЮИ проблема. При запуске Дебаггера все работает корректно. В чем проблема, понять не могу. Буду очень признателен за помощь, т.к. время подпирает конкретно....

Собственно код ЮИ:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>№</th>
        <th><ftm:message bundle="${i18n}" key="ord.id"/></th>
        <th>Parts id</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Total sum</th>
        <th><ftm:message bundle="${i18n}" key="ord.delete"/></th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="ord" items="${orders}" varStatus="status">
    <tr>
        <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
        <td>${ord.id}</td>
        <td>${ord.parts_id}</td>
        <td>${ord.quantity}</td>
        <td>${ord.total}</td>
        <td><form action="frontController?command=deleteord" method="post">
            <button value="${ord.id}" name="deleteOrd" class="btn">Delete</button>
        </form></td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Контроллер вывода:

```
public class OrderController implements Controller {
    private OrdService ordService = OrdServiceIpl.getInstance();

    @Override
    public void execute(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        User user = (User)req.getSession().getAttribute("user");
        List<Ord> orders = ordService.getByUserId(user.getId());

        req.setAttribute("orders", orders);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher(MAIN_PAGE);
        dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Контроллер удаления:

```
public class DeleteOrdController implements Controller {
    private OrdService ordService = OrdServiceIpl.getInstance();

    @Override
    public void execute(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String id = req.getParameter("deleteOrd");
        long ord_id = Long.parseLong(id);
        ordService.delete(ord_id);
        String contextPath = req.getContextPath();
        resp.sendRedirect(contextPath + "/frontController?command=orders");
    }
}
```

Сервисный слой:

```
 @Override
    public int delete(Serializable id) {
        try {
            return ordDao.delete(id);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new SecurityException("Ошибка удаления Ord по id " + id);
        }
    }
```

Сервисный:

```
    @Override
public List<Ord> getByUserId(long userId) {
    try {
        return ordDao.getByUserId(userId);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        rollback();
        throw new SecurityException("Ошибка получения заказов по userId" + userId);
    }
}
```

ДАО:

```
    public List<Ord> getByUserId(long user_id) throws SQLException {
        psGetByUserId = preparedStatement(getByUserId);
        psGetByUserId.setLong(1, user_id);
        psGetByUserId.execute();
        ResultSet rs = psGetByUserId.getResultSet();
        List<Ord> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            list.add(populateOrd(rs));
        }
        close(rs);

        return list;
    }

public int delete(Serializable id) throws SQLException {
            psDelete = preparedStatement(deleteOrdQuery);
            psDelete.setLong(1, (long) id);
            return psDelete.executeUpdate();
    }
```

Подозрений нет... ПОМОГИТЕ

Comment: Какой код используется для отправки данных пользователя на сервер?

Comment: Пользователь заходит на сайт, авторизуется, данные закидываются в сессию(user id), после этого где необходимо взять их "User user = (User) req.getSession().getAttribute("user");"

Comment: Если сессия падает, то где вы возьмете их?

Comment: Если сессия упадет, то соответсвенно не будет id пользователя, из-за этого не сможет произойти запрос товаров по id... Но без сессии с id невозможно выполнить AuthFilter.java, а следовательно и получить доступ к товарам конкретного пользователя. В нем такой код: "HttpSession session = req.getSession();
            if((session.getAttribute("user") == null)) {
                res.sendRedirect(contextPath + "/frontController?command=email");
                return;
            }"

Comment: Мне кажется, что дело в синхронизации потоков или в транзакциях. Хотя, со стороны сервера в деббаге все нормально. Предполагаю, что есть косяк с транзакциями и потоками(Мб фантомное чтение, или грязное). Через 5 минут закину видео, как это работает.

Comment: Ну это если у вас пользователь работает с разными сессиями. OWASP рекомендует сразу удалять сессию при запросе после авторизации.

Comment: https://youtu.be/Y_0EdS12Aw8 вот проблема на видео. Сейчас попробую

Comment: "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" - если добавить 5 товаров подряд, а потом решить удалить, то иногда выскакивает такая вещь.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен. В DAO слое создавалось несколько объекте соединения создавалось несколько preparedStatement. И из-за этого были такие пляски. 
Решение - статический блок:

```
{
    try {
        psSave = ConnectionManager.getConnection().prepareStatement(savePartsQuery, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        psUpdate = ConnectionManager.getConnection().prepareStatement(updatePartsQuery);
        psGet = ConnectionManager.getConnection().prepareStatement(getPartsQuery);
        psGetAll = ConnectionManager.getConnection().prepareStatement(getAllPartQuery);
        psDelete = ConnectionManager.getConnection().prepareStatement(deletePartsQuery);
        psGetByCategory = ConnectionManager.getConnection().prepareStatement(getByCategory);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    } finally {
    }
}
```